# Why program couldn't enter into ABAP event?

Tags: abap

I've made additional save button for ALV screen. Button is described within GUI-status.

```
FORM user_command  USING u_ucomm  TYPE sy-ucomm
                   CHANGING c_selfield TYPE slis_selfield.

Data: lv_is_bayer   TYPE c,
      lt_rows  type salv_t_row.

CASE u_ucomm.
  WHEN '&SAVE'.
```

But it's not working, despite the fact, that the same code in another project executing just fine. In debugging mode there's no access to that part of code on button pressed. So, where should i look for the problem?

Comment: Please provide a complete example, not just some random snippet.

Comment: Uhm, there's too much of not necessary code, and a problem part is really that small. &SAVE - is a function of 'ALV_STATUS' of GUI-status, it should call the part on top... but it didn't. I don't even know, where to look at now...

Comment: Looks like i should update screen through CL_SALV_TABLE, but still looking for proper way to do so.

Comment: Is your GUI-status active?

Comment: Yes. It's displayed on alv, but didn't bear any functions. I'm using cl_salv_table - may be there's the reason...

Comment: If you don't know where to look, start from scratch with a working program and approach your current solution until it stops working. Chances are you'll find the answer yourself then - if not, update the question. With the information you've provided so far, all we can do is guess. That's a waste of time for everyone, including you. A systematic approach is always favorable.

Comment: At least add the code from where you call this subroutine.